# I tried to login with Facebook and another account was created

Tags: support, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

How can I merge my two accounts?

This one making this post my real account and  https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29798/luiz-borges-gomide-nascimento was created when I tried to login.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login with your current account and THEN add new OpenID, not when you're logged out!

You can now simply flag a post which will be describing that you want to delete that account (if you can't do so) and you can connect it with the existing one